# how to run .in (dot 'in') file in cygwin

Tags: cygwin

Is there any way to run .in file? For example ./a<.filename.in
I was able to do this in the Linux system but can't figure out how to do it in cygwin. 
If it is possible, what should i download from the cygwin setup?

Comment: Depends on what the file contains. What is the context? `./a<.filename.in`: what's ***a***?

Comment: 'a' is a filename. It is created by using g++. So it should be ./filename1<filename2.in

Comment: A `<filename>.in` is often a text file containing an initial version, or template used by a software's build system to create the `<filename>` file. You need to run, at least part, of the build and install process to create the `<filename>` file. Look for a text file named something like README or INSTALL which will have some instructions on how to do this.

Comment: have you tried to build `a` with cygwin g++ compiler ?

Comment: @DougHenderson's answer is correct. I would just add that usually there is a configure script that converts <filename>.in to <filename>. The <filename>.in contains macros that configure will substitute based on what's passed to it, and what it determines of your system.

<filename>.in is itself typically generated from a <filename>.am from a program called automake. Usually that's done by the package developer though, and you don't have to worry about that.